# Loading an Image into Imageview

Tags: android, json, image-loading

I am facing problem while trying to call *ImageLoader's DisplayImage function*, actually not getting what i need to use **to Display Image**:

```
 imgLoader.DisplayImage (....);
```

I am writing an App in which I need to Load an Image into ImageView, but always getting blank in place of Image, please see below image:

[image]

**Note:** I don't know what i need to use, in this line:

```
  ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());      
  imgLoader.DisplayImage(url, loader, imageView);
```

*So Please just show me the code, what i need to write to show image in ImageView, 
according to my code*

I am using Localhost to fetch Image, Please see below code using to get Images-

```
private static final String URL_ALBUMS = "http://10.0.2.2/songs/albums.php";
private static final String TAG_IMAGE = "imagepath";

String image = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);

HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
// adding each child node to HashMap key => value
map.put(TAG_IMAGE, image);

protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog after getting all albums
    pDialog.dismiss();
    // updating UI from Background Thread
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(

    AlbumsActivity.this, albumsList,
    R.layout.list_item_albums, new String[] { TAG_ID,
    TAG_NAME, TAG_IMAGE, TAG_SONGS_COUNT }, 

    new int[] {
    R.id.album_id, R.id.album_name, R.id.list_image, R.id.songs_count });

    // ImageLoader class instance
    ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());

    // here i don't know how to call DisplayImage function   
    imgLoader.DisplayImage (....); // what to write here    

    // updating listview
    setListAdapter(adapter);
         }
    });
```

**Note-** I have added all *required classes* in my Project, classes are:

```
      ImageLoader.java, FileCache.java, MemoryCache.java & Utils.java
```

*data.php:-*

```
 1 => array(
        "id" => 1,
        "album" => "127 Hours",
        "imageurl" => "images/onetwentyseven.png"
         ............
```

Note:- As you can see, i am using *local images*, those i have *stored* in **localhost in images** folder.

*JSON:-*

```
[{"id":1,"name":"127 Hours","imagepath":"images\/onetwentyseven.png","songs_count":2},{"id":2,"name":"Adele 21","imagepath":"images\/adele.png","songs_count":2}]
```

Comment: is ur image displayed in browser properly

Comment: @Stacks28 yes i can see my image in Localhost path where i have saved

Comment: Do u have write External storage permission in ur manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code in **AlbumsActivity.java** :

```
ImageView thumb_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.list_image);                  
ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());      
imgLoader.DisplayImage(TAG_IMAGE, thumb_image);
```

Comment: i am facing problem in this, my PHP Code encoding this path in JSON : - http:/\/\localhost/\images/\adele.png which is creating problem to fetch image

Comment: Hi, I have same problem when I want to use localhost imagepath

Comment: With imageloader i had tried loading image from content provider,local device sdcard ,drawable folder in project,url from remote server.So, my question is am i able to get the image from localhost kind of server like from xampp server which is running in the same developing machine.

Answer (score 1):

Url  = "Your image url" //ex:- www.abc.com/images/img.jpg

```
Drawable drawable = LoadImageFromWebOperations(Url);
  imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {

    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exc=" + e);
        return null;
    }
```

}

Comment: Downvoted because it doesn't seems as answer. This should be in comment section.

Comment: @ManishAndroid sorry about that bro.. but i've changed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
                            imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
            configuration = ImageLoaderConfiguration
                    .createDefault(getActivity());
            imageLoader.init(configuration);

            options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showStubImage(R.drawable.default_image)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.default_image)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.default_image)
            .cacheInMemory().cacheOnDisc()
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();

            imageLoader.displayImage(user_bean.getmImage(), mProfileImage,
                    options);
```